# In what way KKT are more efficient or "rigorous" than what I did here?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, maxima-minima, lagrange-multiplier, karush-kuhn-tucker

I solved this exercise and I wanted to ask you in what way using KKT conditions, which here I did not use / wrote down, would have made (IF) the solution better / shorter or the procedure more rigorous.

I have to minimize $z = (x-3)^2 + (y-4)^2$ subject to $x + 2y \leq 8$, $4x + y \leq 10$ and $x \geq 0$, $y\geq 0$.

*Solution*

$$L = (x-3)^2 + (y-4)^2 - \lambda (x+2y-8) - \mu (4x + y - 10)$$

Thence

$$
\begin{cases}
2x- 6 - \lambda - 4 \mu = 0 \\\\
2y - 8 - 2\lambda - \mu = 0 \\\\
\lambda(x+2y -8) = 0 \\\\
\mu (4x + y - 10) = 0 \\\\
x + 2y \leq 8 \\\\
4x + y \leq 10
\end{cases}
$$

Now: if $\lambda = \mu = 0$ I get $y = 4$, $x = 3$ which is not admissible.

If $\lambda \neq 0 $ and $\mu = 0$ I got $x = \frac{4}{5}$ and $y = \frac{18}{5}$ which is admissible. In particular here $\lambda < 0$

If $\lambda = 0$ and $mu \neq 0$ I got $x = \frac{27}{17}$ and $y = \frac{62}{17}$ which does not satisfy.

If $\lambda$ and $\mu$ are both $\neq 0$ I got $\lambda < 0$, $\mu < 0$ and $x = \frac{12}{7}$ and $y = \frac{22}{7}$ which is ok.

And this is indeed the absolute minimum.

- I have been told from our professor that the multipliers must be positive. So why those are negative and still the result hold?
- As you can see, I did not wrote down KKT conditions entirely because for what I understood from the class, the Lagrangian should hae taken into account also terms like $\rho x$ and $\sigma y$ after having turned $x \to -x$ and $y \to -y$, and also writing in the system $\rho x = 0$ and $\sigma y = 0$.

So why / how my result is correct even with less multipliers and incomplete KKT conditions?

If for some reason I understood wrong something, please point it out.

Comment: You say the constraint is $x+2y \le 8$ but you add the term $\lambda (x-2y-8)$. Which is correct?

Comment: @ZoeAllen Sorry, I miswrote. Editing...

Answer (score 2):

It's because your Lagrange equation is non-standard. If the constraints are

$$
\begin{aligned}
0&\geq g(x,y) \\
&=x+2y-8
\\
\\
0&\geq h(x,y) \\
&=4x+y-10 
\end{aligned}
$$

The Lagrange equation in standard form is given by $z+\lambda g(x,y) + \mu h(x,y)$. You use negative sign, which is why your solution has negative multiplier.